# Google API Accessing Gmail from Java with id_token from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, google-api, gmail-api, google-oauth

I'm using the `gapi` to get `googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token` in JavaScript via OAuth2 that I send to my server. I then want to use the Java API to access the Gmail API to list the messages on the account, but I'm getting the following error when I try to access it:

```
[error] com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
[error] {
[error]   "code" : 401,
[error]   "errors" : [ {
[error]     "domain" : "global",
[error]     "location" : "Authorization",
[error]     "locationType" : "header",
[error]     "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
[error]     "reason" : "authError"
[error]   } ],
[error]   "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
[error] }
```

Forgive the Scala code, but this is what I'm invoking:

```
val gmail = new Gmail.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("myapp")
        .build()
val response = gmail.users().messages().list(userId).execute()
```

The `userId` I'm getting from the Java API's profile lookup (which works great), it's just trying to access the `Gmail` instance that is giving me trouble. I've searched but am having a hard time finding any information on this specific situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much digging and bad Google documentation, I finally figured out that I was using the `user.getAuthResponse().id_token` when I should have been using the `user.getAuthResponse().access_token`. Annoying that it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, but hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Building the `GoogleCredential` was as simple as:

```
private val credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().build().setAccessToken(accessToken)
```

Comment: Thanks, its helpful.